# Create categorical variables using R based on percentage of black people in given area

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am new to R (and coding in general), so my apology if I do not use the appropriate terminology.
I want to create 3 categorical variables based on the percentage of black people living in a given area.
For instance:

```
HighBlack = 1 if a city has over 40% of black residents and 0 otherwise.
MidBlack=1 if a city has between 10% and 40% of black residents and 0 otherwise.
LowBlack=1 if a city has less than 10% black people and 0 otherwise.
```

I use to following code to create the variable HighBlack. Note that all the cities included have over 40% of black residents.

````
```pedestrian_stops$High_Black<-ifelse(pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE == 'Sumner - Glenwood' | 'Willard - Hay' | 'Near - North' | 'Folwell' | 'Phillips West' | 'Cedar Riverside' | 'Webber - Camden' |'Ventura Village' | 'Hawthorne' |'Jordan' | 'Harrison' , 1, 0)```
````

I get the following error message:

```
"Error in pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE == "Sumner - Glenwood" | "Willard - Hay" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"
```

What to do? I have tried in vain looking at ways to create categorical variables on youtube and other blogs.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Cathy

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of the operator "OR" `|`. You would need to apply it to an equivalency (`==`) for each of the strings in your list.

i.e.:

```
pedestrian_stops$High_Black <- 
   ifelse(pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==  'Sumner - Glenwood' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==   'Willard - Hay' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==   'Near - North' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==   'Folwell' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==   'Phillips West' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==   'Cedar Riverside' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==   'Webber - Camden' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==  'Ventura Village' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==   'Hawthorne' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==  'Jordan' | pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE ==   'Harrison' , 1, 0)
```

As that is cumbersome, I would suggest you use `{dplyr}`'s pipe in operator `%in%` with a list.

```
library(dplyr)

list_of_neighborhoods <- c('Sumner - Glenwood','Willard - Hay','Near - North','Folwell','Phillips West','Cedar Riverside','Webber - Camden','Ventura Village','Hawthorne', 'Jordan','Harrison')

pedestrian_stops$High_Black <- 
   ifelse(pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE %in% list_of_neighborhoods, 1, 0)
```

Comment: This works! Thank you for taking the time to help me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned by Nicolás, consider making a list:

```
high_percentage <- c('Sumner - Glenwood','Willard - Hay','Near - North','Folwell','Phillips West','Cedar Riverside','Webber - Camden','Ventura Village','Hawthorne', 'Jordan','Harrison')
```

Then assign to a new variable as follows:

```
pedestrian_stops$High_Black <- as.integer(pedestrian_stops$LOCATION_ZONE %in% high_percentage)
```

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you taking the time to help me.